# How to write a single file while reading from multiple input streams in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, file, stream

How to write a single file while reading from multiple input streams of the exact same file from diffrent locations with NodeJS.

### As its still not Clear Maybe?

I want to use more performance for the download lets say we have 2 locations for the same file each can perform only 10mb down stream so i want to download a part from the first location and the secund in parallel. to get it with 20mb.

so both streams need to get joined some how and both streams need to know the range they are downloading.

i have 2 examples

```js
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')

// will write to disk __dirname/file1.zip
function writeFile(fileStream){
  //...
}
// This example assums downloading from 2 http locations
http.request('http://location1/file1.zip').pipe(writeFile)
http.request('http://location2/file1.zip').pipe(writeFile)
```

```js
var fs = require('fs')

// will write to disk __dirname/file1.zip
function writeFile(fileStream){
  //...
}

// this example is reading the same file from 2 diffrent disks
fs.readfFile('/mount/volume1/file1.zip').pipe(writeFile)
fs.readfFile('/mount/volume2/file1.zip').pipe(writeFile)
```

### How i think that it would work

ReadStream needs to check if a defined content range is already writen befor rereading the next chunk from each file and maybe they should start in on a random location in the file to read.

if the total file content length is X we will divide it into smaller chunks and create a map where each entry has a fixed content length so we know what parts we got and what parts we are downloading in total.

### Trying to answer this question my self

We can try to simply optimistic raise Read

```
let SIZE = 64; // 64 byte intervals
let buffers = []
let bytesRead = 0  

function readParallel(filepath,callback){
fs.open(filepath, 'r', function(err, fd) {
  fs.fstat(fd, function(err, stats) {
    let bufferSize = stats.size;


    while (bytesRead < bufferSize) {
      let size = Math.min(SIZE, bufferSize - bytesRead);
      let buffer = new Buffer(size),
      let position = bytesRead
      let length = size
      let offset = bytesRead


      let read = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, offset, length, position);
      buffers.push(buffer);  
      bytesRead += read;
    }

  });
});
}
// At the End: buffers.concat() ==== "File Content"
```

fs.createReadStream() has an option you can pass it to specify the start

```
let f = fs.createReadStream("myfile.txt", {start: 1000});
```

You could also open a normal file descriptor with `fs.open()`, then `fs.read()` one byte from a position right before where you want the stream to be positioned using the position argument to `fs.read()` and then you can pass that file descriptor into `fs.createReadStream()` as an option and the stream will start with that file descriptor and position (though obviously the `start` option to `fs.createReadStream()` is a bit simpler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Range Locking

The Answer is Advisory Locking it is as simple as Torrent does it

1. assign the whole file or a part of it to multiple smaller parts
2. lock the file range and fetch that range from a list of sources.
3. use the file created in part 1 as driver for a FIFO Queue it contains all meta

To get a File from Multiple Sources a JS Implementation would look like
if we assume all files are only i put no error handling in here

```js
const queue = [];
const sources = ['https://example.com/file','https://example1.com/file'];
const fileSize = fetch({sources[0],{method: 'HEAD'}).then(({ headers })=>headers['Content-Size']);

const targetBuffer = new UInt8Array(fileSize);
const charset = 'x-user-defined';

// Maps to the UTF Private Address Space Area so you can get bits as chars
const binaryRawEnablingHeader = `text/plain; charset=${charset}`;

const requestDefaults = {
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': binaryRawEnablingHeader,
    'range': 'bytes=2-5,10-13'
  }
}

const downloadPlan = /* some logic that puts that bytes into the target WiP */
// use response.text() and then convert that to byte via
// UNICODE Private Area 0xF700-0xF7ff.
const convertToAbyte = (chars) => 
  new Array(chars.length)
    .map((_abyte,offset) => 
        chars.charCodeAt(offset) & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `csv-parse` with `csv-stringify` from the [CSV Project](https://csv.js.org/).

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const parse = require('csv-parse');
const stringify = require('csv-stringify')

const stringifier = stringify();
const writeFile = fs.createWriteStream('out.csv');

fs.createReadStream('file1.csv').pipe(parse()).pipe(stringifier).pipe(writeFile);
fs.createReadStream('file2.csv').pipe(parse()).pipe(stringifier).pipe(writeFile);
```

Here I parse each file separately (using a different `parse` stream for each source), then pipe both to the same `stringify` stream which concatenates them, then write to destination.

Comment: The problem is a diffrent we are talking about the exact same file so it should simply download from both locations to bundle the IO.

Comment: What's the problem? You can read the same file twice. Just rename `file2.csv => file1.csv` it should work.

Comment: the problem is that i want to have the double IO in out put via reading from both locations in parallel while the result is the same single file that it would be if i download from a single location same for file system reads and writes.

Comment: So you want some function to synchronize both readable streams and make sure only one of them is outputted? Then why do you need both resources? Please edit your answer and clarify this point.

Comment: Avraham your right i will not drop any of that streams i need to get more performance each stream will get parts that the other don't needs to download so the result is that a download would take half of the time.

Comment: OK, now I understand. It's quite complex to perform such a task. FYI, there is a free software called **BitTorrent** designed exactly for this kind of tasks.